# The jenkins parallel at the same time using pop() to a global list, lead to Cannot pop() an empty List?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

need help
The problem of multiple threads sharing global variables in Groovy or Jenkins DSL

I have tried all sort of ways but nothing seems to be working. Here is my jenkinsfile.

```
def fill_list() {
    def test_list = []
    for ( int i = 0; i < 160; i++ ) {
        test_list.add(i)
    }
    return test_list
}

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Init Workspace') {
            steps {
                script {
                    test_list_generate = fill_list()
                //  println(test_list_generate)
                   }
            }
        }
        stage('Example Stage 2') {
            parallel {
                    stage('stream_1') {
                    agent { label 'infraTest' }
                        steps {
                            script {
                                while (test_list_generate.size() != 0) {
                                    sleep 4
                                    println(test_list_generate.size())
                                    println(test_list_generate.pop())
                                    println("node executor num: ${env.EXECUTOR_NUMBER}")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    stage('stream_2') {
                    agent { label 'infraTest' }
                        steps {
                            script {
                                while (test_list_generate.size() != 0) {
                                    sleep 3
                                    println(test_list_generate.size())
                                    println(test_list_generate.pop())
                                    println("node executor num: ${env.EXECUTOR_NUMBER}")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve these problems?Please change the label in the code to your local valid label

2021-05-11 23:04:47.221  Also:   java.util.NoSuchElementException: Cannot pop() an empty List
2021-05-11 23:04:47.221         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.pop(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:8841)
2021-05-11 23:04:47.221         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$483.doMethodInvoke(Unknown Source)

Comment: i would say it's impossible with jenkins pipeline.  because the same steps could run on different nodes and variables could be serialized to be shared between nodes - so, variables could not be concurrent.

Comment: it's possible but need reasonable manner, i think

Comment: list.asSynchronized()  may be helpful , but so far it hasn't been successful

Comment: you could try to use `def list=new java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue()` and  something like `while( (x=list.poll()) ){ println x }`. but again - if you have several nodes don't expect it will be 100% synced.